# Exiting Everyplay interface causes resolution or camera matrix to change

Tags: everyplay

When I exit out of the everyplay interface sometimes it will cause my entire unity rendering window to shift to the left and up by about 25%.

It seems to only happen the second time the everyplay interface is closed.

Answer (score 2):

The latest 1.0.8 SDK introduced a change to Unity plugins native code level,
could you try commenting out

```
/* Force orientation check, orientation could have changed while Unity was paused */
UIInterfaceOrientation orientIOS = UnityGetGLViewController().interfaceOrientation;
ScreenOrientation orientation = ConvertToUnityScreenOrientation(orientIOS, 0);
UnitySetScreenOrientation(orientation);
```

from your projects Assets/Plugins/iOS/EveryplayUnity.mm and see if it works better
without it?

Comment: and as of the just released 1.0.11 SDK, we found more test cases where this happens and we've now fixed them. Please let us know if you still have issues after re-importing the Everyplay.unitypackage into your project